# DES Algorithm Identifier

Tags: des, pkcs#7, smime

Can somebody please give me an authoritative reference that **1.3.14.3.2.7** is the DES algorithm identifier used in S/MIME? I figured the number by sending a DES encrypted email and viewing the P7M file of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list of OIDs [OIDs Used with S/MIME](http://www.imc.org/ietf-smime/other-smime-oids.asn) is maintained by the Internet Mail Consortium and it is referenced in RFC 2633 p. 7. It clearly mentions that the OID for the DES algorithm in CBC mode is **1.3.14.3.2.7**.

Answer (score 0):

The [OID repository has it here](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.14.3.2.7&action=display). It parses it as:

**{ iso(1) identified-organization(3) oiw(14) secsig(3) algorithm(2) }**

and it oddly describes it as *"Voice encryption using DES (56 bit) in CBC mode and 512-bit DH-group"*.

For the record, **oiw** stands for the OSI Implementor's Working Group.

Comment: Thanks man, however if there's some RFC or something more standard it would be great!